# Why isn't dateFormat for exporting working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to export a chart to an excel file but I can't get the `dateFormat` options to work no matter where I put it.

I'm using this angular module for highcharts: [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

What this does is separating some options to watch them (you can read the faq for the module where he explains), and normal highcharts options goes into the `options` object, as I've done:

```
handler.chartConfig = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      type: handler.getTypeFromId(graph.type)
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
      },
      line: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false // TODO: MAKE THIS A TOGGLE FUNCTION
        },
        enableMouseTracking: true,
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.key:%Y-%m-%d}</b><br/>'
        }
      },
      area: {
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.key:%Y-%m-%d}</b><br/>'
        }
      },
      areaspline: {
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.key:%Y-%m-%d}</b><br/>'
        }
      },
      column: {
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.key:%Y-%m-%d}</b><br/>'
        }
      }
    },
    exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      /* THIS IS THE THING THAT DOESN'T WORK */
      csv: {
        dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: graph.name
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: null,
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Interactions'
    }
  },
  series: null,
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work when I do the export, why this is I have no idea.. Been playing around with it for a while now but I've come up short every time.

I'm using a custom button for this which looks like this:

```
<a class="eo-xls" download="exported-graph.xls" type="text/csv">Export to XLS</a>
```

And when I click it this runs (currently have to click twice but will fix that later):

```
eo.exportXLS = function() {

  var graph = $('.exportable').highcharts(),
      data = new Blob([graph.getTable()]);

  $('.eo-xls').attr('href', URL.createObjectURL(data));        
}
```

Why isn't the `dateFormat` option working here?

Comment: so you get the data in excel file but the date format is not the same as you expected?

Comment: What's data you are seeing inside the generated XLS? Can you please give me a screenshot of that? Or a screenshot of console.log(graph.getTable());

Comment: @WiltsC I'm getting something along the lines of 147039383830 which is seconds since 1970, that's what I'm using on the x axis and then using dateFormat in the actual graph, which is working just fine.

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes that is correct.

Comment: Sorry, just a doubt, do you export the chart to your excel or just the data for the chart?

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle with `highcharts-ng` and `export-data` plugin in jsfiddle? Simple demo with static data will be enough. As I can see, [Export Data](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) plugin works fine. So there must be something in `highcharts-ng` or in `series.data`.

Comment: @RahulSharma The data for the chart.

Comment: @PawełFus I don't have the time to set it up right now but will give it a try when I can.

Comment: I am not sure how your export function works, but if it uses series.options.data then that might be a reason why you see datetime in milliseconds format, since series.options.data stores date in milliseconds,

Comment: @RahulSharma - it doesn't matter. Highcharts always stores data as timestamp, never as date. The plugin should take care of translating timestamp to other format, just like in the plugin's demo page.

Comment: @PawełFus I tried to check it in the debugger and noticed If I extract the contents of `series.options.data` after calling `setData`, I get the date in that data in milliseconds (given I sent them in milliseconds). So it seems that till that point it doesn't convert it to timestamps.

Comment: That's correct. Highcharts always **store** x-values as timestamps. Plugin `Export data` translates on the fly timestamps to dates [here](https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv/blob/master/export-csv.js#L126). @Chrillewoodz I suggest to remove `xAxis.categories` from your options, it may mess up things, still live demo would be great.

Comment: @PawełFus I can't remove categories? How would I then display values on the xAxis?

Comment: If you could setup jsfiddle with your demo, then I could tell you that. Currently I don't know anything about your data so I can only guess. In short, change format from: `data: [value, value, value]` to `data: [ [timestamp, value], [timestamp, value], [timestamp, value] ]` and remove `categories` and set `yAxis.type = "datetime"`.

Comment: @PawełFus Just go to highcharts home page and go to line chart and look at how its data is structured, mine is identical.

Comment: Ok, then change the format to the one I suggested above - it will work.